# Convert each row of pandas DataFrame to nested JSON object

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dataframe that has several columns like [name, email, country, city, type, time, x_completions] as follows:

I want to convert each row of this dataframe to a JSON object but group some columns into a dict and call it `user_info` like `{ "name": "XYZ", "email": "XYZ@gml.com", "country": "USA", "city": "NYC"}`

Basically, I want to convert each row into a JSON object of the following structure:

`{
   "type":"Login",
   "user_id":"002203293023",
   "user_info":{
      "name":"XYZ",
      "email":"XYZ@gml.com",
      "country":"USA",
      "city":"NYC"
   },
   "other_info":{
      "x_completed":"4"
   },
   "time":1562932893
}`

I'm not sure how to go about converting groups of columns to dicts within JSON objects. All the other similar questions on SO deal with some form of `groupby` operation which I don't think I need here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to iterate through each row in your dataframe.

```
[{
   "type": "Login",
   "user_id": row['user_id'],
   "user_info":{
      "name": row['name'],
      "email": row['email'],
      "country": row['country'],
      "city": row['city']
   },
   "other_info":{
      "x_completed": row['x_completions']
   },
   "time": row['time']
} for _, row in df.iterrows()]
```